# How to rename javascript predefined functions

Tags: javascript, function, jsp, rename

Is it possible to rename a predefined function in JavaScript as we do with php :

```
<?php
rename_function('mysql_connect', 'connect' );
?>
```

Comment: `var connect = mysql_connect;` ;)   (of course, both names will now be usable)

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: some more answers will be honored

Comment: SALMAN. My approach is to make the functions name universal cause when usually i write scripts i mixup with the function names for e.g. I mixup strlen(php) with length(js) function. Is my approach right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible in js too. See this function.

```
function rename_function(obj, oldf, newf){
    obj[newf]=obj[oldf];
    delete obj[oldf];
}
```

Here `obj` is the closure of the function. Normally if your functions have no closure it's under window object. `rename_function(window, 'alert', 'al')`

Comment: My approach is to make the functions name universal cause when usually i write scripts i mixup with the function names for e.g. I mixup strlen(php) with length(js) function. Is my approach right ?

Comment: No renaminging function isn't good approach. Besides it decreases readability of the code

Comment: by the way there is a little typo in your answer at 'possiblein' it should be possible in

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im obj[oldf]=**null**;